# Can you force java to return an object by value?

Tags: java

In Java, can one force a method to return by value (not by reference)?

For example:

```
public Rect getBounds() {
    return bounds; //TODO: Return bounds by value so users can't change edit it.
}
```

Here I might as well just make bounds public. There seems to be no reason to create a function to return something if its going to pass it by reference.

My other option is to create several methods return the specific members of bounds 1-by-1 but I would rather not.

Comment: Objects cannot be returned by value, given that there is no concept of assignment by value in Java.

Comment: You could create a new copy of the object with the same values and return that.

Comment: bad idea to make `bounds` public and remove the `getbounds` altogether.

Comment: No, but you might still want the method. Java  Beans, possible future optimizations and refactorings, etc.

Comment: You could return `bounds.clone()`

Comment: This is all great feedback. Since this is my first question I would appreciate it if someone can clue me in on why I may have been down voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is why APIs often return [defensive copies](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15), [unmodifiable wrappers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29), etc.

These copies and/or wrappers (help) prevent users from modifying instance data.

If correct behavior relies on instances having full, and sole, control over instance data, instances are responsible for *ensuring* that behavior by not giving clients anything they can use to break that contract.

Answer (score 3):

Make `Rect` immutable, by making its fields final, assigning their values in the constructor and not creating setter methods.
Immutable objects have many benefits, with thread safety being one of them.

Comment: This does not work in my case because the Rect object does need to be motified. I just didn't want it to be changed via reference.